# What Is JXTitledPanel in Java NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, panel, palette

What is the JXTitledPanel? What it is an older version of JPanel? Or what?
I use the NetBeans IDE version 8, but I don't see the JXTitledPanel in the palette.
Please explanation.

Answer (score 0):

JXTitledPanel comes with the swingx package, which is a 3rd party library project created / maintained by Swinglab that extend the swing components.

to be able to use it, I believe that you have to install the 3rd party library, but as of now I think its already been dead for some times.

I've never been using this myself, but a little of googling helped with this conclusion.

Comment: no need to thnk me, instead you can accept this as answer.